# Can convolution layer learn to calculate the standard-deviation of the input data?

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution, standard-deviation

Say that we have some input data, ground truth label, and a neural network. Then we use those data and label to train the model and get some results.

For some reason, we found that instead of using the original data as input, calculating the local standard deviation of the data and use that as input can get us a better result. Here is an example of calculating the local standard deviation, it's from [here](https://matlabtricks.com/post-20/calculate-standard-deviation-case-of-sliding-window):

```
h = 1;                      % for half window size of 3
x = [4 8 1 1 1 7 9 3];      % input signal
N = length(x);              % length of the signal

o = ones(1, N);             % array for output
for i = 1 : N
  % calculate standard deviation using the built-in std command
  % for the current window
  o(i) = std(x(max(1, i - h) : min(N, i + h)));
end
```

So, here is my question: instead of calculating the local standard deviation by ourselves, is it possible to use a convolution layer and let the model learn to perform such an operation by itself?

If we cannot do that by using a single convolution layer, can we do that by using a more complicated model?

If we can do that, then I have another question: why cannot a model learn to perform a batch normalization operation by itself? Why people nowadays still need to add batch normalization layer manually?

I have done some research on google and here is something I got. Though I'm still a little bit confused:

https://matlabtricks.com/post-20/calculate-standard-deviation-case-of-sliding-window

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch normalization translates and rescales the tensor after standard normalization. The link in your question just gives a way to efficiently proceed standard normalization.

From a statistics point of view, standard normalization decreases the degree of freedom (dof) in the input tensor, while the two learnable parameters in batch normalization add back these two dofs. It is unclear how you can come up with a convolution layer with two parameters (dof) that does something similar batch normalization as the convolution layer can have much more parameters when the window size changes.